# Tabla de precios responsive

Tags: css, bootstrap

[image: tabla que hice con bootstrap]
Diganme, ¿cómo hago una tabla de precios con css y hacerla responsive con bootstrap? Intenté hacer con cards de bootstrap pero la altura no es igual para todos los precios y me molesta, ayudenme por favor.

Este es mi codigo:

```
<section id="precios" class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="card col-sm-5 col-lg-3 p-0 m-1 text-center">
      <div class="card-header"><h2 class="card-title">TS3</h2></div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">10<sup>$</sup></h3>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim tenetur qui tempore nam, praesentium amet!</p>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-block">Comprar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Amigo tienes que investigar la documentación de Bootstrap tiene muchas cosas que te vana gustar

Comment: publica código y foto de como sale, no somos adivinos, ni hacemos tarea

Comment: es verdad, no puse codigo porque me obligaban a colocar un parrafo mas largo

Answer (score 1):

Ya lopude resolver le aplique un min-height para que todos los precios tuvieran la misma 
altura, y posicione los elementos de adentro con position absolute (le aplique position relative al precio para que los elementos no se salieran del contenedor

Comment: igual me gustaria saber otras sugerencias para hacer la tabla de precios

Comment: Hola @felilxlozada. Esto no es una respuesta, mas bien es una ampliación de tu pregunta. Deberías editar tu pregunta, añadir esta información y eliminar esta respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: En mi pregunta pregunte como hacer una tabla de precios porque tenia el problema de la altura, y aqui estoy respondiendo como resolver ese problema con el mismo codigo que puse en mi pregunta, por lo tanto si es una respuesta

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo usar `flexbox`, eso funciona para hacerlas **responsive**

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS

`min-height` es útil pero eso solo te ayuda para la distribución, 
las `flexbox` se adaptan para cualquier dispositivo dependiendo del ancho del dispositivo que le definas.

Comment: Hola @nayelihernandez, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Estaría bien que añadieras un pequeño ejemplo y explicación del código.

Comment: @nayelihernandez esta respuesta ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad, y parece más un comentario/recomendación que una respuesta en sí. Deberías editarla para añadir más detalles: ¿cómo sería lo que se pide en la pregunta usando flexbox? ¿podrías poner une ejemplo? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, yo usaría CSS GRID en lugar de Boostrap, es mucho mejor.

Comment: Por favor no uses la zona de respuestas para hacer comentarios o recomendaciones, por favor lee  [answer], edita y mejora tu aporte

Comment: Lo quiero aprender pero si no me equivoco no es compatible con todos los navegadores, por eso me quedo con bootstrap

Comment: @Aprendiz y alan yo veo una respuesta válida, no es la correcta pero es válida.

Comment: @JesusMolero esta respuesta ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad, y parece más un comentario/recomendación que una respuesta en sí. Deberías editarla para añadir más detalles: ¿cómo sería lo que se pide en la pregunta usando CSS grid? ¿podrías poner une ejemplo? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.